# How to split string from pattern?

Tags: node.js, express

How to put checks on pattern in Express?

I have a url:

```
http://localhost:3030/total?id=1234#12
```

I get the complete url by `req.url` which contains:

```
/total?id=1234#12
```

Is there any string pattern match syntax in Express, like I would like to separate the `/total?id=` part.

Comment: I can't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to ensure presence of `id` in query then it have nothing to do with url patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for `req.query`. That will give you an object based on the keys and values in your query string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both req.path and req.query to separate /total?id=1234#12.

req.path will give you "/total"

req.query.id will give you "1234#12"